# finding path which will give minimum energy

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, data-structures, recursion, graph

ACM International Collegiate Programming Contest, Asia-Amritapuri Site, 2011
Problem A: MAGRID

Thanks a lot for helping Harry Potter in finding the Sorcerer's Stone of Immortality in October. Did we not tell you that it was just an online game ? uhhh! now here is the real onsite task for Harry. You are given a magrid S ( a magic grid ) having R rows and C columns. Each cell in this magrid has either a Hungarian horntail dragon that our intrepid hero has to defeat, or a flask of magic potion that his teacher Snape has left for him. A dragon at a cell (i,j) takes away |S[i][j]| strength points from him, and a potion at a cell (i,j) increases Harry's strength by S[i][j]. If his strength drops to 0 or less at any point during his journey, Harry dies, and no magical stone can revive him.

Harry starts from the top-left corner cell (1,1) and the Sorcerer's Stone is in the bottom-right corner cell (R,C). From a cell (i,j), Harry can only move either one cell down or right i.e., to cell (i+1,j) or cell (i,j+1) and he can not move outside the magrid. Harry has used magic before starting his journey to determine which cell contains what, but lacks the basic simple mathematical skill to determine what minimum strength he needs to start with to collect the Sorcerer's Stone. Please help him once again.

> Input (STDIN):
>
> The first line contains the number of test cases T. T cases follow.
>   Each test case consists of R C in the first line followed by the
>   description of the grid in R lines, each containing C integers. Rows
>   are numbered 1 to R from top to bottom and columns are numbered 1 to C
>   from left to right. Cells with S[i][j] < 0 contain dragons, others
>   contain magic potions.
>
> Output (STDOUT):
>
> Output T lines, one for each case containing the minimum strength
>   Harry should start with from the cell (1,1) to have a positive
>   strength through out his journey to the cell (R,C).

Constraints:

```
1 ≤ T ≤ 30
2 ≤ R, C ≤ 500
-103 ≤ S[i][j] ≤ 103
S[1][1] = S[R][C] = 0
```

Time Limit : 3 s
Memory Limit : 64 MB
Sample Input:

```
3
2 3
0 1 -3
1 -2 0
2 2
0 1
2 0
3 4
0 -2 -3 1
-1 4 0 -2
1 -2 -3 0
```

Sample Output:

```
2
1
2
```

Explanation:
Case 1 : If Harry starts with strength = 1 at cell (1,1), he cannot maintain a positive strength in any possible path. He needs at least strength = 2 initially.
Case 2 : Note that to start from (1,1) he needs at least strength = 1.

I tried with my first approach to see all path and choose the one with minimum energy

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<stack>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int TT,R,C,S[500][500];
int energy_g;
//unsigned long int fact(int a);
int trace(int r,int c,int energy,int energy_r);
int main(void)
{

    cin>>TT;

    for(int i=1;i<=TT;i++)
    {
    cin>>R>>C;     
    for(int r=1;r<=R;r++)
         for(int c=1;c<=C;c++)
         {
             cin>>S[r][c];
         //cout<<S[r][c];   
         }
     energy_g=32000;
     trace(1,1,0,0);
     cout<<energy_g<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

int trace(int r,int c,int energy,int energy_r)
{
    if(r>R || c>C)
        return 0;
    energy += S[r][c];
    if(energy < 0)
    {
    energy_r+=abs(energy)+1 ;       
    energy+=abs(energy)+1;
    }


    else if(energy == 0){        
    energy_r +=1;   
    energy +=1;
     }

    if(r == R && c == C)
    {

    if(energy_r < energy_g)
            energy_g = energy_r;
        return 0;
    }
    trace(r,c+1,energy,energy_r);
    trace(r+1,c,energy,energy_r);
    return 0;
}
```

please help me to optimize it further as I know the method I implemented takes worst time

Comment: Hint: work *backwards*, and every time you calculate the energy needed to get from some position (i, j) to the end, remember it so that you don't have to compute it again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution on the top of my head. We will use quite common trick - binary search on an answer. Solution can be divided into two parts:

1) Check whether we can complete the journey with the health level of N. This can be done with a simple dynamic programming - let `dp[i][j]` be the largest energy level we can have when we move into cell (i,j). Since we can only move down or right, `dp[i][j]` can be concluded as the best of the moves from (i-1,j) and (i,j-1). If the level goes under 1, set the value to minus infinity, because we cannot afford Harry to die :) (or add check to exclude impossible tiles when doing DP steps). `dp[0][0]` is N and `dp[i][0]`, `dp[0][i]` can be computed right off. Then proceed with table-like filling. To visualize, take a look at figure 6.4 of http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap6.pdf.

2) Do binary search on an answer. Originally `left = 1` and `right = 2000000000` (or other suitable upper bound) - those are left and right bounds for binary search. At each iteration of binary search we check whether we can complete the journey with the health level of `mid = (left+right)/2` and recurse into appropriate half.

This will work well in practice - each DP step takes O(R*C) time, and binary search adds a factor of log(2000000000) which is around 30. This should be fine.

It might be solvable with DP only, but I cannot see how right now.

Comment: No need for binary search. Elaborating on @j_random_hacker's hint: you can compute the minimum required energy for each cell of the bottom row directly, starting from right to left. Same for the rightmost column, starting from bottom to top. And other cells can be computed once their bottom and right neighbors are computed.

Comment: That is definitely slight inefficient that binary search